# rCharts NVD3 Plot eliminate gaps in dates on x axis

Tags: r, nvd3.js, rcharts

I want to eliminate the gaps on the x axis and also eliminate the overlapping.

Reproducible example:

```
require(quantmod)
require(rCharts)
aapl <- getSymbols("AAPL", from="2013-12-13", auto.assign = FALSE)
aapl.df <- data.frame(
  index(aapl),
  coredata(aapl)
)
colnames(aapl.df) <- c("date","open","high","low","close","volume","adjusted")
n1 <- nvd3Plot(
  x = "date",
  y = "close",
  y2 = "volume",
  data = aapl.df,
  type = "linePlusBarChart",
  height = 400,
  width = 800
)
n1$templates$script = file.path(n1$LIB$url,'layouts',"linePlusBar.html")
n1$xAxis(tickFormat =
  "#!function (d) {
            return d3.time.format('%b %d, %Y')(new Date(d));
          }!#"
)
n1
```

Produces:
[image]
Also, why does the chart start on Dec 12 2013 when the data begins Dec 13 2013?

```
> head(aapl.df)
        date   open   high    low  close   volume adjusted
1 2013-12-13 562.85 562.88 553.67 554.43 11856400   554.43
2 2013-12-16 555.02 562.64 555.01 557.50 10078600   557.50
3 2013-12-17 555.81 559.44 553.38 554.99  8163900   554.99
4 2013-12-18 549.70 551.45 538.80 550.77 20180200   550.77
5 2013-12-19 549.50 550.00 543.73 544.46 11439600   544.46
6 2013-12-20 545.43 551.61 544.82 549.02 15548100   549.02
```

Last, a bonus question -- I would like to hide the Y-axis label on the left of chart, but still leave the tooltip in place.

Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK that degree of flexibility/configurability isn't really exposed. You would have to modify/hack the generated Javascript.

Comment: Surely you don't need to hack javascript to make the dates accurate.

Comment: That's probably a timezone/parsing issue. Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with rCharts to help with that.